# Which Visa or pass required for attending software workshop in Singapore?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, business-travel

I am joining an entrepreneurship program in SG and traveling on 10th July. I applied for EntrePass Visa on 12 june but i think it'll still take some time to get IPA letter so i can't enter in SG as of now.
What is my best bet to enter in Singapore till I get EntrePass Visa? A work pass/tourist visa?

I'm from India.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  You will need a business visa, see the duplicate answer for details.

Comment: @jpatokal I searched across the web and couldn't find any info about the business visit visa. I talked to my agent also and he said only tourist visa are offered for short term visit. you can check the official page https://www.mfa.gov.sg/Overseas-Mission/Chennai/Visa-Information

Comment: The short term Entry Visa applies to both business and tourism.